# Python Excelwriter overwriting excel sheet

Tags: python, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I am trying to overwrite excel sheet with excelwriter.
but sheet is not overwritten but new sheet is added.(new sheet name is test1, test11....)
below is my code

```
    with pd.ExcelWriter(self.filename, mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace', engine="openpyxl") as writer:
        self.df_holders.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test')
```

is there any problem in my code?

Comment: I have the same issue and none of the answers below help. Mainly because if the mode is changed to 'w' then the whole file is overwritten, and other sheets are deleted. 
But if mode append 'a' is used then sheets are not replaced, instead it adds a new sheet with a numeric counter, so if I write the file 10 times I'll get 10 sheets with the same name and a numeric value at the end.
Also xlsxwriter doesn't take if_sheet_exists option. And for openpyxl in the documentation it says the if_sheet_exists option only work if the mode is append.

Answer (score 2):

Mode `a` means append (which yust means continue writing at the end), so so will never be able to overwrite anything.
Rather use mode `w` which stands for write allowing you to overwrite.
For more info check the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(self.filename, mode='w', if_sheet_exists='replace', engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    self.df_holders.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test')
```

Hope this helps. :D

Comment: Or just don't provide `mode` at all, as `'w'` is the default

Comment: @DeepSpace sure but than he wont understand what he did wrong, judging by the question his pretty new to programming so writing down everything to sort of get what it does isnt all too bad

Comment: You can explain what was wrong, then explain that `mode='w'` is the default

Answer (score 1):

You code is alright! Just upgrade your pandas version to latest using `conda install pandas=1.4.3`, the problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

you can change  mode to "w" or "w+"

Comment: 'w' or 'w+' overwrites the file and all existing sheets are lost.

Answer (score -2):

**Using "xlsxwriter" as your engine will fix the problem**

You don't even need "if_sheet_exists=replace" because xlsxwriter will replace anyways and if sheet doesn't exit, it will create one.

**This is the working example**

```python
with pd.ExcelWriter(self.filename, engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
        self.df_holders.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test')
```

Comment: The problem is with the mode used, not the engine.

Comment: this is one interesting awnser.

Comment: Of course you can use openpyxl and different mode, but xlsxwriter is a lot faster :)

Comment: this also helps. ths